# Multi-step procedure best run together in one procedure or separated into their own procedures?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Note that the database has lots of data (>1 TB).

We are formulating a process that will crawl over our user's data (in batches - can't do every user in one go) so that we can give them information on any anomalies that they might have in their application - we will insert everything we find into a table to format for the user's easy viewing. There are **30+** items to check, most are very rare but we need to get through each of them for every user that gets included in a particular batch.

For efficiency's sake would it be better to run each of these checks (and their requisite inserts) in one procedure or more? 30+ of them?

If it's the latter would it be at all useful to run every user in the batch against each of these tests together? I.e. instead of us running test A, B, C, D,... for each user it would be test A for user 1, 2, 3, 4, ... then test B for user 1, 2, 3, 4,... Not sure if the cache or execution plan in SQL Server would be able to optimize one more efficiently over the other.

Comment: There just isn't enough here to offer much input. Overall I doubt the performance is going to be much different from any of the approaches you mention. It is going to be about 30 queries for each user unless you can use aggregation and group by user. But the absolute best way to test for performance is to create the procedures and [run your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: I figured as much - just didn't know about the latest SQL version's optimizations that might come into play. Thank you.